# MVC Razor Html form validation not catching errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to make a simple form that takes in two required inputs and one optional input (also has one property that is 'hidden' - `TaskId` - and set upon loading, and is not changed after being set).

The problem occurs when submitting. The validation is completely skipped, doesn't matter what I put in the box it always goes straight to the method and doesn't display any validation text to the user. Additionally, the ModelState is always valid regardless.

---

### Update

Posting text instead of pictures. Sorry about that guys.

**View**

```
@model ScrumBoard.Models.ViewModels.UpdateTaskViewModel
@{
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditTask", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new {    @class = "px-4 py-3" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.TaskId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(o => o.Title)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(o => o.Description)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.Description, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 3 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(o => o.Comment)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 2, maxlength = 100 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Description)
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class UpdateTaskViewModel
{
    public UpdateTaskViewModel(int taskId)
    {
        TaskId = taskId;
    }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTask(int taskId, string title, string description, string comment = "")
    {
        Alert alert;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                DatabaseOperations.UpdateTask(
                    taskId,
                    title,
                    description,
                    EacId,
                    comment);
                alert = new Alert("Success!", "Updated task.", "alert-success");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                alert = new Alert("Error!", "Failed to update task.", "alert-danger", e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert = new Alert("Warning!", "ModelState is invalid.", "alert-warning");
        }

        TempData["Alert"] = alert;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Dont post the pics instead of text. Can't copy source code from pics and cant repoduce the problems. People dont have time for typing

Comment: @DanNguyen just updated post, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Why aren't you passing your model back to the controller instead of those string params?

Comment: Ah, silly me. Let me see if that's what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a simple answer... All that needed to be done was instead of passing each parameter individually to the controller method, just pass the ViewModel and everything works as it should:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditTask(UpdateTaskViewModel model)
{
    Alert alert;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseOperations.UpdateTask(
                model.TaskId,
                model.Title,
                model.Description,
                EacId,
                model.Comment);
            alert = new Alert("Success!", "Updated task.", "alert-success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            alert = new Alert("Error!", "Failed to update task.", "alert-danger", e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_UpdateTask")
    }

    TempData["Alert"] = alert;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

PS. Because this is a partial view that I'm using to generate the form, I needed to send back the partial view with the error-ed model back to the main view which I just set in the `@using(Html.BeginForm(...))` to replace the html with the partial view.